# Save a form to a html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a "mentor network" where professionals can put down some basic contact information so people who want or need the mentor can go and search them up. Essentially what I want to do is after someone inputs all the info into my form I want it to create a new html document and write the variables to that document. I have some Javascript and a basic form (the part that has the stars is the part I am unsure of.)

```js
if (window.localstorage) {

  var txtUsername = document.getElementById('username'); //Get form elements
  var txtjobd = document.getElementById('jobd');

  txtUsername.vvalue = localStorage.getItem('username'); //Elements populated
  txtjobd.value = localStorage.getItem('jobd'); //by localStorage data

  txtUsername.addEventListener('input', function() { //Data saved
    localStorage.setItem('username', txtUsername.value);
  }, false);

  txtjobd.addEventListener('input', function() { //Data saved
    localStorage.setItem('jobd', txtjobd.value);
  }, false);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="application" action="new.html">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <br/>
    <label for="jobd">Job Descrition</label>
    <br/>
    <textarea id="jobd" name="jobd"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
<script src="js/local-storage.js"></script>
```

I was attempting to save the new variables created to the new.html, and my other problem is that this first doesn't create a new document and 
second would only save and rewrite to the one new.html
So those are the problems I'm trying to solve and feel free to tell me that Im going at this from the wrong angle, im new to JavaScript, Also I have considered that Jquery might be the way to go, if you think so please tell me.

Comment: You can't create a new html file on the server with client-side Javascript alone - you need something like PHP or NodeJS on the server to do this for you. A better way to get where you want to go would be to use a server side language like PHP to save your data into a database, then instead of having 100's of html files, use one PHP file to show the data for a single mentor from the database. Unfortunately PHP is far too broad a subject to teach in one question.

Comment: Something of significance - You have a typo at `txtUsername.vvalue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you'll need PHP for this.

If you were a client coming to me with this idea, I would instantly think $5k to $20k budget (in other words, you seem to not comprehend how complex and difficult this sort of thing is). But if you strictly only need a form that creates a HTML page, and I stress, **nothing more than this**, it is possible to do it with minimal PHP knowledge.

[Someone provided a tutorial on creating a .txt file from a form](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/17187-form-text-file.html) - given you're new to all this but have managed to get this far, I'm sure you will be able to play around and take it further.

**The form:**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="signup.php"> Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>Email: <input type="text" name="mail"><br>Experience: <select name="exp"> <option value="beginner">Beginner</option> <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option> <option value="advanced">Advanced</option> </select><br> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up"> </form>
```

**The .php file that creates the .txt:**

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['user'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$experience = $_POST['exp'];

//the data
$data = "$username | $email | $experience\n";

//open the file and choose the mode
$fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);

//close the file
fclose($fh);

print "User Submitted";
?>
```

Remember, this will only create a simple .txt file. There won't be any index of these files, there won't be the ability to edit, there won't be user accounts - these are tasks that would take hundreds of hours, excluding learning all of this and knowing how to code without security issues.

I would suggest contacting a PHP developer if you're serious about this project - or be prepared to start learning a lot! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you , I guess php is the way to go then.